# S-function not found by Simulink unless rebuild

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink, s-function

I am currently using Matlab Simulink with a Raspberry Pi. I have been using the S-Function Builder block to generate an S-Function that I am using with the S-Function Block. However, I always need to keep a copy of the S-Function builder that I need to build at the first start, as Simulink otherwise tells me :

"Error in S-function 'read_accelerometer/S-Function': S-Function 'sfun_read_adxl345' does not exist"

I am keeping the .c and the wrapper.c file, as well as the mexw64 and the tlc files. But that does not matter - I still have to rebuild the S-Function using the Builder block every time I reload my model.

How to circumvent this issue?

Comment: mex and tlc on the search path?

Comment: All of them, the sfun.c, the sfun_wrapper.c, the .mexw64 and the .tlc are at the root of the path.

Comment: The sad part of this is that now that I have copied the S-Fun Builder inside my model, I am getting another error:

"undefined reference to `sfun_read_adxl345_Outputs_wrapper'"  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is kinda sad that I am answering my own question ...
I had a startup script that messed with the mexw64. So, always keep the mexw64 file, even if it is not needed. (recompilation on Raspberry Pi)
Also, specify the generated wrapper function as a module in the S-Fun block.